# How to find id of duplicate records in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Table Entry has the following data. Certain records are duplicate. Duplicate criteria is same NoOfEntry and TypeOfEntry. Out of a record which has same NoOfEntry and TypeOfEntry, i want the EntryId of record which has min(dateOfEntry).

For Eg- We have 3 duplicate records for T1, I want record with EntryID 1001 as it was enterd first(minimum DateOfEntry).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a CTE (Common Table Expression) with a `ROW_NUMBER` ranking function:

```
;WITH duplicates AS
(
    SELECT 
       EntryID, DateOfEntry
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NoOfEntry,TypeOfEntry
                          ORDER BY DateOfEntry DESC) 'RowNum'
    FROM dbo.Enty
)
SELECT EntryID FROM duplicates
WHERE RowNum > 1
GO
```

The CTE will "partition" your data by `(NoOfEntry,TypeOfEntry)` and start assigning sequential numbers (1, 2, 3, .....) to each row for each group of those two columns.

Any row that has a `RowNum > 1` is a duplicate, based on `(NoOfEntry,TypeOfEntry)`

Comment: Thanks for the CTE example. Is this possible using a groupBy?

Comment: yup no probs i asked just out of curiosity.